# Segmentation fault in insertNode function at the line with for loop declaration. Any suggestions?

Tags: c

My program is supposed to extract all of the words out of a input file and put them into a linked list. When I run and debug the code I get a segmentation fault in the insertNode function at the line with the for loop. I cannot figure it out. Any suggestions/solutions/advice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct node
{
  char *data;
  struct node *next;
};


void insertNode(struct node**, char *);
void printList(struct node*);


int main()
{
  struct node *head = NULL;
  FILE *fptr;
  char file_name[20];
  char str[1000];
  int numOfChar;


  printf("Enter the name of the file: ");
  scanf("%s",file_name);


  printf("Enter the number of characters per line: ");
  scanf("%d",&numOfChar);


  fptr=fopen(file_name,"r");

  while(fscanf(fptr, "%s ", str) != EOF)
  {
      insertNode(&head, str);
  }

  fclose(fptr);
  printList(head);


  return 0;
}


void insertNode(struct node** Head, char *data)
{
    struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "insertNode() malloc failed!\n");
        return;
    }
    new_node->data = strdup(data);
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (*Head == NULL)
    {
        *Head = new_node;
         return;
    }

    struct node* tail;
    for (tail = *Head; tail->next != NULL; tail = tail->next)
        /* intentionally blank */ ;

    tail->next = new_node;
}

void printList(struct node* node)
{
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %s ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to use a debugger.

Comment: @kaylum i did. The debugger just said there is a segmentation fault like i said above. Do you know why this is happening?